# Running c# async method in f# workflow

Tags: f#, async-await, c#-to-f#

I am trying to get the below code to work in a F# async workflow, but I am getting the error "Unexpected symbol '}' in expression". I am fairly new to both F# and async in general.  What am I missing here.

```
let someFunction (req : HttpRequestMesssage) a b = 

    // code
    async{
        let! readToProvider =
            req.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider)
            |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult 

    } |> Async.RunSynchronously

    req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I worry that my previous answer wasn't quite what you want.  What I supplied just got you through the compile error.  But one thing about it, is that it does *not* run asynchronously.  `Task.Wait` and `Async.RunSynchronously` will both block the running thread until the operation is complete.

If you want to actually *be* async, i.e. not blocking, you have to put the entire method, or at least the last part of it, into the `async` block, such that you're actually returning an `async` op to the caller.  So the answer would be

```
let someFunction (req : HttpRequestMesssage) a b = 
  async {
    let! readToProvider = (req.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync provider) |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult 
    return req.CreateResponse HttpStatusCode.OK
  }
```

*This* option returns not the response, but an `Async<Response>`.  So now the *caller* can decide how to run it, either blocking or truly asynchronously.

This way if you're using a web server that handles asynchronous requests, then you can simply connect this function to an endpoint (probably converting the `Async` to a `Task` at the point of connection, since most .net async web servers are written from C# perspective) and it'll run asynchronously without blocking a thread.  Or if you're calling it from another async op you can do `do! someFunction ...` and it'll run asynchronously.  But if the caller doesn't care and just wants to run synchronously, it can do `someFunction ... |> Async.RunSynchronously`.  So you get more flexibility there.  And you can always define `let someFunctionSync ... = someFunction ... |> Async.RunSynchronously` if that's the more common use case.

I'd recommend going this way unless you really want to enforce blocking.

Answer (score 5):

You're doing it right.  You're only getting the error because you're ending your `async` block with a `let!` expression.  Change it to `return!`, or `do! ... |> Async.Ignore`  and you'll be good.

Blocks in F# (neither workflows nor regular code blocks) should not end with `let`.

Of course if *all* you're *really* doing in the workflow is that *one* call, you don't need the workflow block at all (you never really should need to write a block for a single call).  Just do

```
req.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync provider
  |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult 
  |> Async.Ignore
  |> Async.RunSynchronously
req.CreateResponse HttpStatusCode.OK
```

Or for that matter, just use the built in Tasks Wait, which does the same thing as Async.RunSynchronously:

```
(req.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync provider).Wait()
```